# node mssql update query, get rowcount

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, node.js, express

I'm using the NodeJS package MSSQL (https://npmjs.org/package/mssql#cfg-node-tds) to connect to a MS SQL database and perform UPDATE queries.

I understand that if an UPDATE query ends up *not* affecting any rows, it will still return as a success event. I would like to handle the success event differently if zero rows were affected since this is not the intended outcome of the query.

After doing some research, I found that when performing SQL queries, you can use @@ROWCOUNT to get the number of affected rows, but I've yet to figure out how to use this with the MSSQL Node package.

Has anyone used this Node package and and handled UPDATE queries the way I am trying to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, right from the link your provided, the node package can call stored procedures.

Either create the logic on the JS side or the TSQL side.

Since I am a DBA/Developer by trade, lets create a SP to perform the update an return the number of rows effected.

I am using the adventure works sample database.

```
-- use sample db
use AdventureWorks2012;
go

-- sample select
select * 
from [Person].[Person]
where lastname = 'Walters';
go

-- stored procedure
create procedure usp_Update_First_Name (@id int, @first varchar(50))
as
begin
    update [Person].[Person]
    set [FirstName] = @first
    where [BusinessEntityID] = @id;
    return(@@rowcount);
end
go

-- make a call
declare @ret int;
exec @ret = usp_Update_First_Name @id = 4, @first = 'Robert';
print @ret;
```

This call returns the following output.

(1 row(s) affected)
1

In the JS code, do action A if @ret = 0 or action B if @ret > 0.

Comment: This sounds perfect! I am certainly not a DBA by trade, so stored procedures are not something I've done before or am familiar with. I will try to implement this into the mssql code based on their stored procedure documentation and see how that goes. Thank you!!

Comment: If you like the answer, please give me the credit.  Best wishes and coding dreams ...

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to create your stored procedure easily in the MSSQL Node code, but I did find a way to run multiple queries at once. This is basically the same as running your stored procedure.

`var request = new sql.Request();
request.multiple = true;
request.query('...update query... ; SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS \'count\'')`
Then check if recordsets[0].count is > 0.

Even though I didn't use your example, it led me to my solution, Thanks!

Comment: Cool beans.  The stored procedure can be created in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) and call by the node package (custom Java Script).